# redirect my web to a specific application on the user device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, web-applications

I'm building a shopping web site which should redirect the user to a spesific application in his device when he click 'submit'.

I'm developing this site with Java Script.

the requirements are:

1) if he uses the site from a computer-the application should not be open.

2) if he uses the site from a device which the application is already installed in- it should be open,

else-playstore ao itunes should be opened in the applicarion page.

now, my problem is with #2- I dont know how to redirect the user to a specific application in his device and automaticly open it.

I dont know the application URL or any API of it.

Is it possible? how?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do this using universal links. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) to the documentation provided by Apple themself. There is even an entire video related to this topic on their website, here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717/). I think these documentations are more than enough for even a beginner to adopt a universal link.

Comment: this option is relevant only if I have the app url..the only url I have is the url for downloading it.

Comment: @ShirCohen Universal linking is the only way you can achieve this. You can't just open any app on any device without consent from the developer and user, it's not secure and has many privacy flaws.